# SQL left and right parts list from a single list (All parts listed)

Tags: t-sql

I have a part list for example:

PartNo, Side, LotNo, BatchNo

Side is either 'Left' or 'Right'. The LotNo and BatchNo for a left and right will match. If a part doesn't have a match, I need to display the part, left or right, with the missing side being blank. This is pretty easy until the last part.

```
Part    Side    Batch   Lot Part    Side    Batch   Lot
122A    Left    10      501 122B    Right   10      501
238A    Left    10      601 238B    Right   10      601
882A    Left    20      801             
                            992B    Right   20      802
332A    Left    20      901 322B    Right   20      901
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have so far?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm trying to make a left + right list together on the same line.

Comment: Can you give some example data and the expected output.

Comment: The true query doesn't match this one, this is simplistic but the answer can be applied to the true query. I have nothing at this point I could share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c4a13/10)

```
SELECT
pl.[Part],pl.[Side], pl.[Batch], pl.[Lot],
pr.[Part] as Part_R, pr.[Side] AS Side_R, pr.[Batch] As Batch_R, pr.[Lot] AS Lot_R
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM part WHERE Side = 'Left') pl
FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM part WHERE Side = 'Right') pr
  ON pl.Batch = pr.Batch 
  AND pl.Lot = pr.Lot
```